# Trying to parse and access the item in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am trying to parse and access the item in a JSON object. How can I access the 'entity' array in my JSON payload?

```
var results = {"id": "92-4dac-4307-9038-c50e829a022a","funa": ["4667"],"entity": [{"id":"98","en": "com","type": "AAF"},{"id":"99","en": "com","type": "AAF"}]};
gs.log(">> raw result: " + results.funa);    //output : 4667
var str = JSON.stringify(results);
var parser = new JSONParser();
results = parser.parse(str);
gs.log(" >> after parse mots: " + results.funa);  //output : 4667
gs.log(" >> after parse id0: " + results.entity.length);  //output : 2

for (var key in results)
    gs.log("Key is: " + key + " and value is: " + results.entity[key]);   //undefined
```

Comment: You should do `for key in results.entity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is tagged with "ServiceNow" and none of the previous answers are sensitive to the nuances of ServiceNow's Rhino engine. ES6 syntax will throw the following error in any server-side script `Javascript compiler exception: syntax error`. At present (Jan. 2022), ServiceNow only supports ES5 JavaScript.

You should use ServiceNow's JSON wrapper for parsing and stringifying your objects. The JSON wrapper code lives in a Script Include called `JSON` which you can peruse.

Several ES5 methods are available to you - including the `forEach()` method. Because entity is an array, we use `forEach()` to iterate over the entity array of objects. Note that this is only one of several ways to iterate over this array.

I've updated your code snippet and added comments to reflect the answer to your question.

```js
var results = {
    "id": "92-4dac-4307-9038-c50e829a022a",
    "funa": ["4667"],
    "entity": [
        {"id":"98","en": "com","type": "AAF"},
        {"id":"99","en": "com","type": "AAF"}
    ]};

gs.info(">> raw result: " + results.funa[0]); // output : 4667

var resultsStr = global.JSON.stringify(results); // Convert result to string

var resultsObj = global.JSON.parse(resultsStr); // Convert resultStr to an object

gs.info(" >> after parse mots: " + resultsObj.funa[0]);  // output : 4667
gs.info(" >> after parse id0: " + resultsObj.entity.length);  //output : 2

resultsObj.entity.forEach(function(entity) { // Use forEach() to iterate through each obj in the entity array
        for (var key in entity) { // Iterate through each key in the current array element
             gs.info("Key is: " + key + " and value is: " + entity[key]); // Access entity array element value from the parsed resultsObj 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach method to iterate over the entity array. Then, to iterate over the properties of each element in the entity array, you can use `for (var key in item)` syntax.

```
results.entity.forEach(item => {
   for (var key in item) {
       gs.log("Key is: " + key + " and value is: " + item[key]); 
   }
});
```

I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand right, but are you looking for something like this?

```js
var results = {"id": "92-4dac-4307-9038-c50e829a022a","funa": ["4667"],"entity": [{"id":"98","en": "com","type": "AAF"},{"id":"99","en": "com","type": "AAF"}]};
console.log("raw result: " + results.funa);    //output : 4667
var str = JSON.stringify(results);
results = JSON.parse(str);

results.entity.forEach(entity => {
  Object.keys(entity).forEach(key => {
    console.log("Key is: " + key + " and value is: " + entity[key])
  })
})
```